# c# if else doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, if-statement

Method DeleteTester should delete line with selected tester from TestingCompany.txt 
If the tester is already assigned into Equipment tester shouldn't be deleted.

My code doesn't work properly. When tester is assigned to equipment it  shows error message "This testing company is assigned to Equipment" and delete tester. Tester shouldn't be deleted.

```
public void DeleteTester(string testerData)
{
    string line_to_delete = testerData;
    string[] line_to_Delete_Array= theEntity.setString(line_to_delete);
    string testerToDelete = line_to_Delete_Array[0];
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\\Temp\\Equipment.txt"))
        if (line.EndsWith(testerToDelete, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This testing company is assigned to Equipment", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else 
        {
            string strFilePath = @"C:\\Temp\\TestingCompany.txt";
            string strSearchText = testerData;
            string strOldText;
            string n = "";
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strFilePath);
            while ((strOldText = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!strOldText.Contains(strSearchText))
                {
                    n += strOldText + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, n);
        }
}
```

Method setString returns array from line in the file

```
public string[] setString(string newString)
        {
            sString = newString;
            setStrings = sString.Split(',');
            return setStrings;
        }
```

Equipments files has information with separator ","

```
1,voltmeter,25/07/2017,1
2,multimeter,31/08/2017,2
3,ampermeter,31/07/2016,3
4,voltmeter,29/08/2016,1
```

Testing Companies file data

```
1,Testing Ltd,2 New North Rd,Auckland,2678
2,Q Testing Ltd, 4 Dominion Street,Auckland,5678
3,Metrology Limited,2 Dominos St,Christchurch,3456
```

DeleteTester()

```
private void btnDeleteTester_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string deleteTester = lstTestingCompanies.GetItemText(lstTestingCompanies.SelectedItem);
            theController.DeleteTester(deleteTester);
}
```

deleteTester has a data `1,Testing Ltd,2 New North Rd,Auckland,2678`

**FIXED CODE** It works, but it is just a pattern and it is not designed well

```
public void DeleteTester(string testerData)
        {
            string line_to_delete = testerData;
            string[] line_to_Delete_Array = theEntity.setString(line_to_delete);
            string testerToDelete = line_to_Delete_Array[0];

            string[] checkEquipment = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Temp\\Equipment.txt");

            foreach (string s in checkEquipment)
            {
                string[] TesterToDelete = theEntity.setString(s);

                if (Convert.ToInt32(TesterToDelete[3]) == Convert.ToInt32(testerToDelete))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This testing company is assigned to Equipment", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag != 1)
            {
                string strSearchText = testerData;
                string strOldText;
                string n = "";
                StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\\Temp\\TestingCompany.txt");
                while ((strOldText = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!strOldText.Contains(strSearchText))
                    {
                        n += strOldText + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Temp\\TestingCompany.txt", n);
            }

        }
```

Comment: When you debug your program, what is the value of `line` and what is the value of `testerToDelete`?

Comment: Post sample data entries

Comment: Yes, please post sample data from both files and what your expected end-result is.

Comment: And what does your `theEntity.setString()` do? If it simply adds the string to the array, the whole thing seems redundant.

Comment: @Sach - your last edit adds brackets that weren't in the original question. My previous edit indented the code after the for loop line without introducing braces in case the OP's lack of braces were part of his problem (hidden by his lack of indentation).

Comment: @hatchet good point, let me change it back. Thanks!

Comment: This may be unrelated, but code like `@"C:\\Temp\\Equipment.txt"` is wrong; you need either `@"C:\Temp\Equipment.txt` or `"C:\\Temp\\Equipment.txt`.

Comment: @Nadia OK that's better. I assume the above sample data is from Equipment file. Please add the other file's sample content as well.

Comment: @Nadia - are you aware that the block of code after the `else` could be executed multiple times, because it is inside your for loop?

Comment: That setString function looks rather redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: And what's the string you pass to the `DeleteTester()` method? As in, the actual string content that you pass.

Comment: Your message-box is inside the `foreach` loop, thus it will be shown multiple times instead of just once. Your `else` to perform deletion is also inside the `foreach` loop, thus it will be deleted multiple times instead of just once. You need the `foreach` loop *only* to check whether tester is already assigned. The deletion should be performed after / outside the loop scope.

Comment: You appear to be doing `EndsWith` with a string representation of a number. This is not a good plan. What happens when you have a company whose number is 11? He'll match a search of 1 or 11. I think you should consider the whole design of what you're doing here. Your current approach seems very, very fragile.

Comment: Thank you Guys, all fixed. Please see fixed code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a fixed version of your code that gets the intended job done. That is, if the first number of the string passed is not assigned to any equipment in the equipment file, it will delete the said line from the company file.

I've removed a bunch of redundant code and cleaned it up.
First up, doing a bunch of other operations while a file is opened is not a good practice. Instead, read the content, close the file, and do your stuff, and if needed to be written back to a file, open and write again. Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

```
public static void DeleteTester(string testerData)
{
    string[] line_to_Delete_Array = testerData.Split(',');
    string testerToDelete = line_to_Delete_Array[0];
    string equipmentFile = @"C:\Temp\Equipment.txt";
    string companyFile = @"C:\Temp\TestingCompany.txt";

    var equipmentData = File.ReadLines(equipmentFile);
    var companyData = File.ReadLines(companyFile);

    foreach (var line in equipmentData)
    {
        if (line.EndsWith(testerToDelete, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This testing company is assigned to Equipment");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            var finalList = new List<string>();
            foreach(var company in companyData)
            {
                if (!company.Contains(testerData))
                    finalList.Add(company);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(companyFile, finalList.ToArray());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.
You get the *This testing company is assigned to Equipment* message because the test data you pass has `1` at the beginning, and `1` is a number assigned to an equipment in your equipment file, hence it will never go into your `else` statement. Try changing your equipment file to below before running this code.

> 1,voltmeter,25/07/2017,555
>
> 2,multimeter,31/08/2017,2
>
> 3,ampermeter,31/07/2016,3
>
> 4,voltmeter,29/08/2016,555

**HOWEVER**

Like many others pointed out, your approach is ***extremely*** fragile and could go wrong in so many places.

---

**SUGGESTION 1**

In your button click event, instead of getting the whole line of test and passing it to the `DeleteTester()` function, extract the number (in your example string, simply `1`) and pass that as an `integer`.

Then in the `DeleteTester()` function use some sort of a proper CSV reader to read your Equipment file, and isolate the reference number at the end of each line, and *convert* it into an `integer`.

Now, instead of your `line.EndsWith()`, do an `integer` comparison and see if it exists or not.

Then, in your `else`, again use a CSV reader and isolate the first number in each line, convert that into an `int`, and if matches, delete your line.

---

**SUGGESTION 2**

Even that is not a very good method. If you really want to be thorough, and I think you should, either use a DB, or if that's an overkill, at least well structured XML files, to store your data.